# ORACLE Not In on Multiple Columns

Tags: sql, oracle

Kindly have a look at the following structure.

```
Table: A
+---------+----------+
| Col1A   | Col2A    |
+---------+----------+
|   1     |    1     |
|   2     |    1     |
|   3     |    1     |
|   4     |    1     |
|   1     |    2     |
|   2     |    2     |
+---------+----------+

Table: B
+---------+----------+
| Col1B   | Col2B    |
+---------+----------+
|   2     |    1     |
|   3     |    1     |
+---------+----------+
```

Here is what I am trying to achieve that is to get the result as following:

```
Result 
+---------+----------+
| Col1A   | Col2A    |
+---------+----------+
|   1     |    1     |
|   4     |    1     |
|   1     |    2     |
|   2     |    2     |
+---------+----------+
```

**What I want :**

I want to get the result of table `A` records which are not exists in Table `B`. It should be on the basis of both column. If the combination exist in first table then don't no show it.

**What I have tried so far :**

The first approach that I have tried was to use `Not In` statement. Following is my statement.

```
SELECT A.COL1A, A.COL2A 
FROM A
WHERE A.COL1A NOT IN (
   SELECT B.COL1B FROM B
);
```

But the issue with this approach didn't consider the second column. It will give me the following result.

```
+---------+----------+
|   1     |    1     |
|   4     |    1     |
+---------+----------+
```

While it will not show following as it should be sub-traced because of we didn't checked for other column.

```
+---------+----------+
|   1     |    2     |
|   2     |    2     |
+---------+----------+
```

Then I tried `Not Exists` but I didn't worked too. Here is my query.

```
SELECT A.COL1A, A.COL2A 
FROM A
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
   SELECT B.COL1B,B.COL2B FROM B
 );
```

**Edit**
Sorry I forget to include the fiddle link.
Here it is : <kbd>[`Fiddle Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/86916/1)</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this which is conceptually simple is to `JOIN` tables `A` and `B` on the two columns, and then `SELECT` only those rows in `A` which do *not* exist in `B`:

```
SELECT *
FROM A
LEFT OUTER JOIN B
ON (A.COL1A = B.COL1B AND A.COL2A = B.COL2B)
WHERE B.COL1B IS NULL
```

Comment: Kindly could you edit given sqlfiddle. i just have added. This query didn't worked. I mean there is no such col as COL1B in Talbe A [In where condition].

Comment: It didn't gives me proper result kindly execute your query on my fiddle and match it with my Result that i have mentioned in my answer. thanks

Comment: I'm getting only 2 records instead of 4. Here is my updated fiddle and result of your query. Kindly check it. 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/86916/2

Comment: According to your OP, you want `Table A records which are not exists in Table B`.  This Fiddle clearly behaves correctly.

Comment: But it also removes the record 1,2 and 2,2 which shouldn't be. It should show these two records too.

Comment: `(1, 2)` and `(2, 2)` do _not_ appear in the Fiddle you are referring to.

Comment: @Zeb-ur-Rehman: your SQL Fiddle doesn't insert the combinations `(1,2)` or `(2,2)` into table a

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the issue. It did the job. :)

Answer (score 3):

For using Exists I think you should use it like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM A
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
               FROM B
               WHERE A.Col1A = B.Col1B AND A.Col2A = B.Col2B)
```

Comment: Here is the updated fiddle. Kindly have a look at the fiddle and result as i'm not getting  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/86916/4

Comment: Thank you very much dear it was my fault as i didn't added last 2 rows in my fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM a
WHERE (col1a, col2a) NOT IN (SELECT col1b, col2b FROM b);
```

But be aware that this will fail if either `col1b` or `col2b` contains `NULL` values.

<kbd>[`SQLFiddle DEMO`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6e1dc1/1)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.COL1A, A.COL2A 
FROM A
WHERE (Col1A, Col2A) NOT IN (
   SELECT Col1B, Col2B FROM B
);
```

You can even use:

```
SELECT A.COL1A, A.COL2A 
FROM A
WHERE (Col1A, Col2A) NOT IN (
   (2, 1),
   (3, 1)
);
```